I'm working on enabling change data capture from MySQL to Apache Kafka with Debezium but im getting an error in the sink connector
Error image 
The error message is as follows:
[2024-09-03 06:57:22,110] ERROR [jdbc-connector|task-0] Failed to process record: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.InternalSinkRecord.originalRecord()' (io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask:112)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.InternalSinkRecord.originalRecord()'
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.getOriginalTopicName(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:223)
        at **io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.markProcessed(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:106)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:605)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-09-03 06:57:30,410] ERROR [jdbc-connector|task-0] JDBC sink connector failure (io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask:95)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.InternalSinkRecord.originalRecord()'
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.getOriginalTopicName(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:223)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.markProcessed(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:106)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:605)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-09-03 06:57:30,410] ERROR [jdbc-connector|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: JDBC sink connector failure (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:633)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: JDBC sink connector failure
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:605)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.InternalSinkRecord.originalRecord()'
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.getOriginalTopicName(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:223)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.markProcessed(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:106)
        ... 12 more
[2024-09-03 06:57:30,413] WARN [jdbc-connector|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-connector-0} Ignoring invalid task provided offset kafka_destination-0/OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''} -- partition not assigned, assignment=[mysql.kafkadb.kafka-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:471)
[2024-09-03 06:57:30,414] ERROR [jdbc-connector|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:233)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:635)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:246)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:215)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:237)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: JDBC sink connector failure
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:605)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.InternalSinkRecord.originalRecord()'
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.getOriginalTopicName(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:223)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.markProcessed(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:106)
        ... 12 more

I tried to enable change data capture from MySQL to Apache Kafka with Debezium
but im getting an NosuchmethodError and  failed to process original record
(),
i'm expecting the data successfully moves to the destination mysql database works for delta load(incremental changes) its completely working for complete snapshot

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What versions of Debezium and Kafka are you using? NoSuchMethodError typically means there is a mismatch
